# how to prevent video download by user in php

Tags: php, video, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I hope you are fine
I want to write a simple php code that the user cant download the movie like youtube site and can only see, I came across a series of results such as hls, ffmpeg, rtmp in my search, but I do not know which one is useful or has a library for php at all or not.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Regular YouTube videos can be downloaded. Do a bit of research on streaming protocols/formats, device support and DRM.

Comment: Seems like you are asking the community to do the research on behalf of you. Moreover, this appears to be a really broad topic and you could narrow it down. Start by looking at what would be the easiest way to integrate an opensource implementation  with your php codebase.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible. The server can not differentiate between “downloading” and “playing”.